# parallel execution in C program

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I have a question about possibility of implementing parallel execution inside a C program.
My code looks like this:

```
struct str {
   field;
   field2;
   struct name * ptrNext;
}

// something others

int main() {
    struct str *pHead = malloc((...)sizeof(struct str));
    struct str *ptr;
    // other.....
    /* Generation of dynamic list*/

    ptr=pHead;

    while(... ... ...) {
          someFunctionOnNode(ptr);
          ptr=ptr->ptrNext;
    }
}
```

To increase the speed of program and to exploit having multiple cores in the processor, I would like to parallelize launch of function `someFunctionOnNode`.

Is there a way to do this in C?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do that is to employ the OpenMP directives supported by virtually all modern C and C++ compilers. If your one is modern enough (i.e. supports OpenMP 3.0), then you could simply use tasks:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    while(... ... ...) {
        #pragma omp task
        someFunctionOnNode(ptr); // This function call becomes a task
        ptr=ptr->ptrNext;
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

This single directive is so only one thread will walk the list and produce tasks, but otherwise all threads will pick a task to execute. The `taskwait` directive waits for all tasks to finish. It is not strictly necessary since there is an implicit barrier synchronisation at the end of the `parallel` region.

If your compiler does not support OpenMP 3.0, you can work around by putting all possible values of `ptr` in a flat array and then performing parallel for loop over it:

```
datatype *ptrs[NUM_PTRS]; // Or allocate with new
int i = 0;
while (... ... ...) {
    ptrs[i++] = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->ptrNext;
}

#omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < NUM_PTRS; i++)
{
    someFunctionOnNode(ptrs[i]);
}
```

You should also enable OpenMP support but how it's done is compiler-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Launch each function in a separate thread.  The threading API depends on what system you're developing on, but if it's UNIX-like check out pthreads:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Check out the [MPI Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

Standard C does not have any parallel processing functionality. Your best bets are using platform dependent multi-threading functions or some other more portable mult-processing API.

Comment: [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) does! (Yeah, did you know there is a C11?)

Comment: Yeah, I did know :) But c11 in mainstream compilers/libraries is experimental at best, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: I know, I was just excited about learning it exists, I wanted to share that knowledge! :D

Comment: +1. I share your enthusiasm :) I hope GCC starts supporting it fully in the near future. I don't have any hopes for MSVC though, since they don't even support C99 yet :/

Comment: I don't even consider MSVC as a compiler

Comment: Let's not start a flame war and just say that it has minuses (non-portable, non-standard) and pluses (you can always use mingw, a big plus).

Comment: No flame wars, but mingw is gcc ported to windows. So the compiler is still gcc (no plus for MSVC ;) )

Answer (score 0):

[OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) is probably the best solution if the processors shear memory,if you have a cluster MPI. 
In OpenMP you just give [pragmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor_directive) to the compiler where you want to the code to run in parallel, so it is easy to adapt your existing code.